# How to add prefix to exported symbols during module building

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to build a kernel module from some source files. Are there any preprocessor flags to add prefixes to the selected routines and than compile those source files. I want to do only the make file changes to achieve these task.

Comment: I would guess there is no way, but I am not sure to understand *exactly* what you want. Please tell what are the common source files in use... Did you consider playing some C preprocessor tricks? Give some source example in your question, so please **edit your question** to improve it... BTW, what is a PF driver? And a VF one?

Comment: Perhaps the common code might be made as *another* module (to be loaded before the two others)? Overall, your question is very unclear...

Comment: Let me put it these way. I want to build a kernel module from some source files. Are there any preprocessor flags to add prefixes to the selected routines in that source files before going to compile the module. I want to do only the make file changes to achieve these task.

Comment: No need to thanks, but you should edit your question... Don't comment it. Edit it.